# PHP - Delete element from multidimensional-array based on value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
foreach ($array_leave_dates as $emp => $leave_type) {
    foreach ($leave_type as $leave_dates) {
       if($leave_type == 'Maternity Leave'){
         unset($array_leave_dates[$leave_type]);
       }
       else{
         echo $leave_dates[$row];
       }
    }
}
```

Here we can fetch $leave_dates and want to remove or unset leave_type == 'Maternity Leave'. But could'nt. Please help to point out the mistake in my code above.

Comment: Show example data of the first array! `$array_leave_dates` Whitout knowing more try `unset($array_leave_dates[$emp]);`  Note: From where comes `$row`?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your data source looks like:

```
<?php
// Remove the whole employee 
$employees = array(
    'emp1' => array('sick' => 'Mon - Tue'),
    'emp2' => array('bun in oven' => '2016 - 2017'),
    'emp3' => array('broken heart' => '2017 - ∞'),
);

foreach ($employees as $emp => $leave) { 

    foreach ($leave as $leaveName => $date) { 

        if($leaveName == 'bun in oven') { 
            unset($employees[$emp]); 
        }
    }
}

print_r($employees);


// OR remove only 'Maternity' from the employee but keep everything else
<?php
$employees = array(
    'emp1' => array('sick' => 'Mon - Tue', 'its friday and im not coming in' => 'Fri'),
    'emp2' => array('bun in oven' => '2016 - 2017', 'sick' => 'Thu'),
    'emp3' => array('broken heart' => '2017 - ∞'),
);

foreach ($employees as $emp => $leave) { 

    foreach ($leave as $leaveName => $date) { 

        if($leaveName == 'bun in oven') { 
            unset($employees[$emp][$leaveName]); 
        }
    }
}

print_r($employees);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the // comments

```
foreach ($array_leave_dates as $emp => $leave_type) {
  // you treat $leave_type as array here
  foreach ($leave_type as $leave_dates) {
   // you treat $leave_type as string here
   // doesn't feel right
   if($leave_type == 'Maternity Leave') {
     // you are unsetting with a value
     //unset($array_leave_dates[ --> $leave_type <-- ]);
     // i assume you want to delete the key 
     unset($array_leave_dates[$emp]);
   }
   else{
     // $row doesn't seem to exist, looks wrong from here
     echo $leave_dates[$row];
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `$leave_type` can be `"Maternity Leave"`, then why do you search for `$leave_dates` inside that string value? The question is naturally rethorical. From the very fact that you have two `foreach` cycles and the second is embedded into the first makes me think that `$leave_type` is not what you think it is. So, I think you have a multi dimensional array, where the outer keys are employee names or ids and the inner keys are the types. Example:

```
array(
    'John Doe' => array('Sickness' => array('a', 'b', 'c')),
    'Mary Doe' => array('Sickness' => array('a', 'b', 'c'), 'Maternal Leave' => array('d', 'e'))
)
```

If that is the case, then you need to modify your cycles:

```
foreach ($array_leave_dates as $emp => $leave) {
    if ($leave['Maternity Leave']) {
         unset($array_leave_dates[$emp]['Maternity Leave']);
    }
}
```

If you want a more general solution, then this might help you:

```
function removeByKey(&$arr, $k) {
    if (arr[$k] !== null) {
        unset arr[$k];
    }
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $arr[$key] = removeByKey($arr[$key], $k);
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}
```